# USACO 2006 FortMoo DP Bug

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am currently doing a practice problem from the USACO 2006 Contest, which is basically the following:

> Given a grid of dots and X's such as
>
> ```
> ......
> ..X..X
> X..X..
> ......
> ..X...
> ```
>
> find the rectangle with the biggest area such that the perimeter of
>   the rectangle includes no X's. For example, the rectangle denoted by
>   the f's is the best possibility.
>
> ```
> .ffff.
> .fX.fX
> Xf.Xf.
> .ffff.
> ..X...
> ```

[Here](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=600) is the original problem statement.

So far, I've written a code that runs with the correct output for 11 out of the 13 test cases, but two of the last test cases don't work. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define INF 0x3f3f3f3f

const int MAX = 200 + 5;
int N, M, MAXAREA = 0;
bool ok[MAX][MAX][MAX], land[MAX][MAX];

int main() {
  /// read in input
  // land[i][j] = 1 if there is a swampy area at (i, j)
  cin >> N >> M;
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
      char ch;
      cin >> ch;
      land[i][j] = (ch == 'X');
    }
  }

  /// precompute crossing lines
  // ok[col][row1][row2]: there are not X's from row1 to row2 in column col
  for(int col = 0; col < M; col++)
    for(int row1 = 0; row1 < N; row1++)
      for(int row2 = row1; row2 < N; row2++) {
        if(land[row2][col]) break;
        else ok[col][row1][row2] = true;
      }

  /// run dynamic programming
  // first loop through all pairs of rows
  for(int row1 = 0; row1 < N; row1++) {
    for(int row2 = row1; row2 < N; row2++) {
      // for each pair of rows, go from left to right for columns. lhs_col = LHS column
      for(int lhs_col = 0; lhs_col < M; ) {
        // find the first LHS column that has no X's at all
        if(!ok[lhs_col][row1][row2])  {
          lhs_col++;
          continue;
        }
        // next_col & last_col are next & last columns that are perfectly clear 
        int cur_col = lhs_col, next_col = INF, last_col = lhs_col;
        // make sure cur_col has top and bottom vertices clear
        while(cur_col < M && !land[row1][cur_col] && !land[row2][cur_col]) {
          // finds the first and last column that are perfectly clear
          if(ok[cur_col][row1][row2])
            next_col = min(next_col, last_col = cur_col);
          cur_col++;
        }
        // get maximum area
        MAXAREA = max(MAXAREA, (row2 - row1 + 1) * (last_col - lhs_col + 1));
        // if there is no next_col that is perfectly clear or the next one is itself
        if(next_col == INF || next_col == lhs_col) break;
        else lhs_col = next_col;
      }
    }
  }

  /// output answer
  cout << MAXAREA << endl;
}
```

And [here](https://justpaste.it/1if53) is one of the input cases that causes it to not work. My code outputs 966 while it should be 1488. The other test case is so large, there is no point in pasting it here. I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Could someone please explain the downvote?

Comment: Absolutely horrible title? It tells someone searching nothing and that makes the question of limited long-term use.

Comment: @user4581301 Could you please tell me how to fix it? I'm fairly new to this, I apologize sorry. :(

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you're essentially asking why your specific, fairly long code doesn't work. You can start minimising your example - does it precompute clear columns properly? does it select a correct rectangle? (not crossing X-es) what's the correct rectangle? (there aren't that many factors of 1488, so you can find it by hand) does your solution reject it? does it find the same corner, but wrong size?
Try to get to a very specific problem yourself first. It will be much easier to help you if you can explain the exact failure rather than us looking for it.

Comment: That's better, but if you have any idea what the bug is, you should focus on that instead. That you have a bug in some code is almost self-evident from asking a question here. The plus side: You actually have a failure case, and that's brilliant. Practically no one asking a question has bothered to figure out a failure case. But have you run this through a debugger to see where the program goes wrong? Side note: you look to have  a brute force solution, if there are any time constraints on the problem you'll likely run into them

Comment: Okay thanks guys :D